# Sqlite query multiple columns and group by them

Tags: c#, sqlite

This is my table:

[image]

I am basically using the following table to pass a select statement and viewing it as a pie graph.The pie graph excludes fields that are null or 0. So First i used the following query to select the total number by its respective group number and it worked fine. This is the working query.

```
query = "Select groupNumber as \"Group Number\", totalNumber as \"Total Number\" From " + table;
```

However i found it hard to read since both columns are numbers and therefore figured it will be better to pass a query where i can select the total numbers by its respective groupName. This is a problem though because if u look at the table you will notice that groupNames can be repeated.

Therefore i would like to do a select satement where i can query the total number by the groupnumber and groupname.
Is this possible if so how? Also i can't modify the data as i receive it in such format from a established connection.

Comment: I'm not sure about what you need. Check [GROUP BY](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) clause.

Comment: I basically want to write a select statement where i can get the total number by groupnumber + groupname

Comment: But your table doesn't have duplicate `(groupnumber, groupname)` tupples!

Comment: Please show some example data, and the desired output.

Comment: The totalnumber column has data for 2 groups that have the same name. That is the issue.